# How do I mark myself as Online in Skype with AppleScript?

Tags: applescript, skype

I just need an AppleScript to mark me as Online in Skype automatically. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This should do it.

```
tell application "Skype" to send command "SET USERSTATUS ONLINE"
```

I know you are new to this site, so I will offer a bit of friendly advice. Generally, when you ask a question here, we want to know that you've actually put forth some effort into your resolving your problem. Sometimes this can include what is known as an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). You might also want to venture over to the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) for more tips on asking good questions.

Happy coding! :)

Comment: It didn't work. It said "Skype got an error: Some parameter is missing for send." (P.S. I did put in some effort before I left this post.)

Comment: @Miles Whoops! I forgot the `script name` parameter. So instead the script would be `tell application "Skype" to send command "SET USERSTATUS ONLINE" script name "online"` Happy coding! :)

Comment: @Miles A bit more helpful advice... When you believe you have found a solution, click the check mark below the vote count of the answer you feel best answers your question. This lets other users know that your problem has been solved. Thanks, and welcome to StackOverflow! :)